# Floating point numbers are printing only the integral part

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have a program like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    double x;
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
    {
        cout << (x = i/100) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On running it, I only get:

```
0
0
0
[...]
```

I've tested this on both Cygwin-g++ and MinGW-g++; both version 4.7.2.
Where could possibly be the problem?

Comment: your program is correct and output is correct too. you need just cast to double.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because as both `i` and `100` are integers, the compiler does integer division.

The easiest way to solve this is to use the `double` literal `100.0` instead:

```
cout << (x = i/100.0) << endl;
```

Comment: Let me think about this a second.. Will that get you a `double` or a `float`?

Comment: @BoBTFish [Floating-point literals are by default doubles.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal)

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast either `i` or `100` to double, e.g.:

```
cout << (x = (double)i/100) << endl;
cout << (x = static_cast<double>(i)/100) << endl;
```

Otherwise, since they are both `int`, the division is performed with `int`s, and only then the result is being converted to double. Of course, before the conversion, you lose everything after the floating point.

Comment: I would avoid casts whenever possible, since 100 could easily just be changed to 100.0 its the more "performant" solution.

Comment: @TehSuu, in this case - yes, but next time the OP might have `i/j`, and face the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change `100` to `100.0` will produce a `double` value:

```
cout << (x = i/100.0) << endl;
//                ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just because `=` is a sequence operator, and a conversion is just done within a single sequence.

So you just do integer to integer arithmetic, where no conversion is needed.

So the integer result will be casted to floating point result, but that time the floating points got already discarded. So you have to make sure in the right part of `=` is a floatingpoint variable used that arethmetic between floatingpoint and integer values is done and the conversion is done.

You can achieve this by typing `100.0` or `1.0`.

Comment: `1f` is not valid C++.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq sure about? I'm using pretty often in my OpenGL app which is implemented in my FLTK project (which is c++). and the MSVC compiler didn't throw any warnings untill today. (And we all know, even the MSV pure c compiler is more C++ as C) So Im a bit confused if it is so.

Comment: A particular compiler is free to accept the syntax `1f`, which can be added to the C++ language without ambiguity (and indeed, is accepted in some C-like languages such as Java). But when answering C++ question, it's best not to use it, without knowledge of the OP's compiler. http://ideone.com/vzUqw3

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq ok, I'll change it, just didn't knew.